# How to refresh the cache of links in Facebook?

Tags: facebook, cache

I recently found out my webpage had been hacked. When viewers would go there it would go to some screwy page.

Now that it's fixed, I can go to my site again, but if I click on a link from my Facebook business page to my site, it goes to the same screwy page.

How often does Facebook refresh it's cache? Is there something I can do meanwhile?

Answer (score 2):

There's no "cache of links" - links are plain-text references to location on the Internet and your computer shows you either the link or whatever destination the link redirects you to. Thus, if you end up on a wrong page, it means either the links on your Facebook business page are pointing to the bad page, or the problem with your site isn't fixed, or your computer serves you old local cache of the *page*.